# How can I store the output of a command as a variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Say I execute the command:
`git pshu`
which will give me:

```
git: 'pshu' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
        push
```

If this was the last command I executed, I want retrieve the command and store its outputs in a variable for further use.

So far I have tried things like:

```
$var = echo (iex (h)[-1].CommandLine)
$var = iex (h)[-1].CommandLine | Out-String
```

etc.

How can I save such output to a variable?

Comment: What you're seeing is error output. It ends up in the standard error stream, which is why your variable doesn't pick it up. `$var = git pshu *>&1` to merge all streams into standard output

Comment: Yea that seems to work. Thanks. Can i add on that?

I want to store the output of the last command i executed.

i found that u could get this using (h)[-1].CommandLine
`$var = iex (h)[-1].CommandLine *>%1` doesn't give me anything. Why is this? Even without the `iex`.

Edited the question.

Comment: `$var = & $^ $$ *>&1` Worked. Is there a better way to get the output(including error stream) of the previously executed command into a variable? I think that only works for commands with 1 argument.

Comment: take a look to my answer it should work ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you are running multiple commands, and you want to store store a run command based on its input.

Lets say you want to store non existing git commands, as `git pshu`. My proposal will be to store the command and search for the desired pattern on the output as `"Did you mean..."`. In this case, you can follow as:

```
$output = git pshu *>&1
if ( "$output".indexOf("Did you mean") -ge 0 ) {
write-host "Command '$($(get-history)[$(get-history).count-1].CommandLine)' didnt exist"
```

where `$(get-history)[$(get-history).count-1].CommandLine` will contain the latest run command, in this example, `git pshu'